# How to get a CardHolder Name

Tags: java, android, emv

I am trying to read a smart card and i have been able to get some data from the smart card. The issue i am facing now is how to get the CardHolder name from the smart card.

i have

```
if(emv_is_tag_present(0x5F20) >=0){
                                tagDataLength = emv_get_tag_data(0x5F20, tagData, tagData.length);
                                if(debug)Log.d(APP_TAG, "Carder "+ tagDataLength);
                                appState.trans.setuserName(StringUtil.toString(AppUtil.removeTailF(ByteUtil.bcdToAscii(tagData,0, tagDataLength))));
                            }
```

I do not really know the format to use in getting this field from the card while trying to use **5F20   Cardholder Name Indicates cardholder name according to ISO 7813 Card    ans 2-26    '70' or '77'    2   26  primitive** which i got from [here](https://www.eftlab.co.uk/index.php/site-map/knowledge-base/145-emv-nfc-tags)

This is the output i am getting 3030303030333830D160222101..but, whenever i try to convert that into a String...it gives back 00000380Ñ`"! which is not really the name of the Cardholder.

Reading through the document (which link is posted there), i am not sure if i am using the correct format in getting my data. cos, in the document, i have  ans 2-26. I do not really understand what it means.

Comment: Do you have a log of what you sent to the card ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag 5F20 - CARD HOLDER NAME, if CARD returning the value of this tag, value will be hex string - **Hex value of ASCII characters** , what you need to do is to convert value to string and you will get the value personalized in the card.

```
in the document, i have ans 2-26. I do not really understand what it means.
```

sometimes we avoid to personalize card holder name inside the card and then we personalize **" /"** - space followed by / = 2 char. It is the minimum value for tag 5F20 defined in different EMV specification. Max value is 26 therefore 2-26 used for Tag 5F20.

Hope this information will help you..

Comment: Thanks so much for this information. I was previously working on a MasterCard (while getting this 3030303030333830D160222101), but on using a Verve Card, i was able to get the name......Does it mean Master Card doesn't have their names inside the Card???....cos, i did not change anything in the code...all i did was just to change the card type

Comment: I did not heard such restriction by MasterCard, I always found 5f20 tag with valid value, if this tag is present in AFL, card will give you same value which is personalized at perso time. what is your steps to read 5f20 tag from EMV card?

Comment: I will Select File, Get Processing options, Read Record then, i will get Data...that is the steps i take...when reading data. But, i am getting a straight output..while reading a verve card...am i getting anything wrong...with the 5f20???

Comment: But, i am getting a straight output..while reading a verve card ??? what does it mean? select file->GPO->Read AFL->Find 5F20 Tag is correct way to get the value of 5F20.

Comment: while using the 5F20, i can get the card holder name...i have tried it on another master card..(GTB) and also all types of Verve card..it works fine...but, on FirstBank(master card), it isn't really working

Comment: it means there are a problem in particular card as you are getting good result for other set of cards. hope you get your answer now.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for your time...although, the card i was previously testing was an expired card...so, i do not think that should be a reason for me not been able to access it....since i can still get other information from it..like the PAN, Expiry date, AID, ICC data...and co.

Comment: if you are satisfy with this conversation you should accept my answer!!!

Comment: thanks for your time...already marked it...wanted to upvote it...but, i do not have much reputation to do that...i really appreciate your time..and also looking forward to exchanging more conversations with you